# How does a class G/H amplifier work?

Tags: amplifier

How does a G/H amplifier work?

What does it do to help with power dissipation?

I am trying to figure out how a G/H amplifier works but so far the documentation and videos on the internet I found  are too complex when explaining how it works. I only understand that a G amplifier has multiple power rails but I don't understand how that helps with power dissipation. I also have a hard time understanding this diagram which I found, especially finding out what parts do what.

[image: simplified G amplifier]

Answer (score 2):

This extends the power saving efficiency technique of Class AB beyond just switching at the zero crossing voltage to switching also at +/- 35V-Vf.

In  Class AB mode  Q2/4 alternate as power drivers to the load at the crossover of 0V bias.  Let's assume Vf=0.5V for simplicity , so Q2-C=34.5V in Class AB mode.   When the signal rises to start conduction  of the  3.3V Zener on the +ve side, the Zener cathode will be 3x 0.65V drops above the collector Q2-C or about 2V+ 34.5V.

So the Emitter Follower Darlingtons amplify the current and the Class GH switches in like AB except instead of just zero-crossing bias controlled by Q9 for split power for Q2/4, the Zener and Schottky diode near 35V crossing  linear switches.  The idle current allows the soft switching for transferring power from 35V supply to the 70V supply in order to reduce the power loss across Q2/4 so that they begin to saturate when  when Q6/8 begin to conduct from +/-70V.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about the overall design and not the details of each transistor, which is covered in other answers.

It is all about reducing the power consumed in an idle state. If you have a 500 watt class AB amplifier that consumes 50 watts during idle state, you need a massive heatsink and possibly cooling fans as well, plus it definitely shows up in the power bill.

In this case we have series output drivers with the 70 volt outputs needing a stronger drive signal to turn on. If signal volume is lower than the trigger values for the 70 volt transistors, only the 35 volt transistors are supplying an idle current.

That is the catch. Say the output is set to idle at 50 mA per pair of output transistors which keeps THD very low. With a +/-35 volt source that is 3.5 watts of idle power. If the supply as fixed at +/- 70 volts then idle watts is 7.0. For a 5,000 watt concert amplifier with +/- 120 volt supply rails and 10 pairs of outputs that becomes a heat management nightmare. Class D uses PWM for efficient output at the expense of higher THD and lower slew rate.

So these low distortion multi-voltage output designs give us a amplifier that waste less power in a idle state or at low volume levels, but instantly activates the higher voltage stage when the volume exceeds a preset limit. At high volume levels most power goes to the speakers and the need for big heatsinks is still there due to the ce resistance being much greater than zero for each output transistor. This design has been used with as many as three power supplies, each one about twice the voltage of the lower voltage.

Note that this is about the drive voltage to the output stage crossing specific thresholds, not the load placed on the outputs. Also remember **power amplifiers often use many pairs of output transistors in parallel** to handle the current of heavy loads (2 ohms to 1 ohm in some cases) and have a very low drive impedance.

**EDIT:** In this design it is very difficult to implement parallel output stages as Q9 is the bias ref for all output stages. Normally very high powered class AB amplifiers cannot use this design, so forced air cooling and/or a DSP driven switch-mode power supply is used to provide just-in-time voltage to the output transistors. Note that supply rails can be as high as +/- 120 volts.

Comment: I always imagined that the multi-stage operation is always on duty even when playing loud. Would the low-voltage stage not supply the current until the output signal exceeded its rated voltage thereby minimising power dissipation?

Comment: @Transistor. You are correct, hence the schottky isolation diodes to prevent 70 volts from backfeeding into the 35 volt supply.

Comment: So it basically chooses a power input automatically depending on the input signal to be amplified?

Comment: @3MPTheRook. Yes, but the input signal level is the driving force. Q9 sets the bias voltage, so the 3.3 volt zener diodes and constant current source need to be carefully chosen to avoid distortion at high volume levels.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is actually a voltage follower. The load gets the same voltage as the input signal. The input signal voltage swings between plus and minus 66 volts. I guess 70V cannot be achieved because the emitter followers need some operating reserve due the numerous base-emitter PN junctions in series. If the 8-like current source symbols contain a boostrap circuit or another voltage rising method, output range plusminus 68V is realistic.

The complexity of the circuit is caused by  a few things:

- transistors can output only unipolar voltages, there's separate voltage followers to both polarities, the upper half is plus side and the lower half is the minus side.
- proper biasing is needed to avoid cross-over distortion i.e. distortion when the signal voltage is low, lower than normal BE voltage drops in transistor BE junctions. The bias circuit adds DC to the signal to make the emitter followers to operate near zero volts.Without biasing one would hear crackling distortion at low output levels.
- outer transistors q6 and q8 block +70V and -70V supplies out of the game when the instantneous signal voltage is so low that plusminus 35 volts is enough. 70V power supplies are in use as soon as the output voltage is out of the range about -34V...+34V.

The reduction of losses:

When a transistor feeds load R from DC voltage E so that the instantneous load voltage is V, the transistor dissipates power Pd=I(E-V) = (V/R)(E-V)

V swings along the signal. We cannot affect V because we have already decided to output a certain signal. But the multiplier E-V becomes smaller if the operating voltage E is reduced. E must be more than V to make the operation possible, but we can reduce average E-V by having lower E when the signal voltage is below a certain limit. In your circuit the "take lower E" switching limit is V=34V.

In class H amplifiers E is taken from a varying output switch mode power supply which tries to stay a little higher than the needed V. The smaller is the difference E-V the lower are the losses in the transistor between E and the load.

The idea can be developed. The transistor between voltage E and the load can be replaced by a wire if E is controlled fast and accurately enough to make E=V.That happens in class D amplifiers. They are actually switch mode power supplies with controlled output voltage.